# Pass a PHP variable in a link to a modal window

Tags: php

Hi I have a php link which calls a modal popup window which all works fine, the problem i am having is that it doesn't pass the php variable in the link.

the php variable shows in the address bar, but it isn't passing to the modal form.

here is my link

```
 echo "<a href=\"?ip_address='.$ip_address.'#accSettings1\" >Add</a>";
```

And I am getting the variable like this.

```
$ip_address = $_GET['ip_address'];  
echo "$ip_address";
```

Answer (score 4):

You need double quotes and not single quotes

```
<? echo "<a href=\"?ip_address=".$ip_address."#accSettings1\" >Add</a>";  ?>
                              -^-------------^-
```

It will pass `.` and `'` as literal string, the output will be something like

Assuming `$ip_address = 'hello';`

```
<a href="?ip_address='.hello.'#accSettings1" >Add</a> <!-- HTML Source -->
                    -^-------^-
             This is why the link breaks
```

so it is adding unnecessary periods and single quotes in the link which breaks it

And the code I provided will be

```
<a href="?ip_address=hello#accSettings1" >Add</a>
```

Comment: The full string (containing the PHP variable) is double-quoted, so it should be replacing it in the string, though the single quotes and `.` operators are therefore unnecessary and are likely being add to the string itself. e.g. `<a href="?ip_address='.127.0.0.1.'#accSettings1" >Add</a>`

Comment: @KyleS Yes I added to the question

Comment: Okay, at first it seemed to imply that `$ip_address` will pass as a literal string, which is not the case. The single quotes and periods will, however.

Comment: HI Thanks, ok i changed the link as you suggested but it still doesn't pass the ip_address, the #accsettings1 is the modal trigger, so is this getting in the way of passing the variable when i roll over the link it shows this    data.php?ip_address=212.250.159.74#accSettings1

Comment: ok the modal is in a table with the fields being added from mysql, if i add a unique number to the modal eachtime would that fix the problem?

Comment: @user1691024 ID's should be always unique, if they repeat, JS won't work

Comment: But thats the thing the modal works fine, i can go up and down the table and every modal opens, but it just doesn't pass the ip_address in to the form on the modal

Comment: @user1691024 I guess you need to take a look at ajax here